# InstaLoader - login from a file or using a password

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api, instaloader

Can it be done like this:

If load_session_from_file fails, for example because the password has changed, is there any way to catch the error and for example authorize via username and password?

Like something like this, but it immediately triggers a warning and falls asleep.

```
try:
    loader.load_session_from_file(auth['username'])
    #try login...
except:
    loader.login(auth['username'], auth['password'])
    loader.save_session_to_file()
    #try login...
```

> Instagram responded with HTTP error "429 - Too Many Requests". Please
> do not run multiple instances of Instaloader in parallel or within
> short sequence. Also, do not use any Instagram App while Instaloader
> is running. The request will be retried in 666 seconds, at 02:47.

Comment: It's a bad practice to put any code inside of the 'except' apart from handling the exception, make your load_session_from_file function to return true if it's successful or false if it's not. Then you problem is solved.

Comment: I already tried this, it returns None but still falls asleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while it came to me:

```
try:
    loader.load_session_from_file(auth['username'], auth['username'] + auth['password'])
except:
    loader.login(auth['username'], auth['password'])
    loader.save_session_to_file(auth['username'] + auth['password'])
```

[!] Safety is out of the question